# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: compiler-errors, npm-install

```
PS F:\ThemeForest__Amit\next-lms\MainFile\File> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: next-lms@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.x || 17.x" from react-image-lightbox@5.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-image-lightbox
npm ERR!   react-image-lightbox@"^5.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\amitb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\amitb\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-22T11_05_58_122Z-debug-0.log
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "next-lms",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^1.2.4",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.17.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "photoswipe": "^5.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^5.0.0",
    "react-countup": "^6.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.3.5",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.10",
    "react-on-screen": "^2.1.1",
    "react-player": "^2.11.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll-to-top": "^3.0.0",
    "react-scroll-up": "^1.3.7",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-tabs": "^6.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "video-react": "^0.16.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

I need only **npm install** this command. No need **yarn or npm install --force**

Beacase I submit my project in themeforest. They dont't want npm install --force. They want only use npm install this command. But if I use this command it say error.

Please anybody help me. What can I do right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```